# Mapping data from mongoDB to Mat UI DataGrid

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I am trying to map data that is queried by my backend to my front end Material UI DataGrid component. I am running into an issue where my page loads for a moment, it queries my database, and I can see it try to render the data, but it goes to a white page. I don't see any error in my console and my back end is performing as it should and has been tested with Material UI's table. Below is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";

import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import { AddCircleOutline } from "@mui/icons-material";

import { userCartsRounded } from "../../api/wowTeamRoutes";

function Rounding() {
  const [cartsRounded, setCartsRounded] = useState([]);

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    userCartsRounded()
      .then((response) => {
        setCartsRounded(response.data);
        console.log("test");
        console.log(cartsRounded);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const columns = [
    { field: "serialNum", headerName: "Cart Serial Number", width: 150 },
    { field: "pcNum", headerName: "Workstation Number", width: 150 },
    { field: "dateLastRounded", headerName: "Last Rounded On", width: 150 },
  ];

  const rows = useMemo(
    () => cartsRounded.map((row, index) => ({ ...row, id: row._id })),
    [cartsRounded]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        color="primary"
        aria-label="new rounding"
        component="span"
        onClick={() => {
          navigate("add_new_cart");
        }}
      >
        <AddCircleOutline />
      </IconButton>
      <DataGrid
        component={Paper}
        rows={cartsRounded}
        getRowId={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Rounding;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop again through the data you get from the api.
Try this:

```
function Rounding() {
  const [cartsRounded, setCartsRounded] = useState([]);

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    userCartsRounded()
      .then((response) => {
        setCartsRounded(response.data);
        console.log("test");
        console.log("test");
        console.log("test");
        console.log(cartsRounded);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const columns = [
    { field: "serialNum", headerName: "Cart Serial Number", width: 150 },
    { field: "pcNum", headerName: "Workstation Number", width: 150 },
    { field: "dateLastRounded", headerName: "Last Rounded On", width: 150 },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        color="primary"
        aria-label="new rounding"
        component="span"
        onClick={() => {
          navigate("add_new_cart");
        }}
      >
        <AddCircleOutline />
      </IconButton>
      <DataGrid
        component={Paper}
        rows={cartsRounded}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
      />
      {roundingModal && <AddRoundedCart />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Gave that a try, but I still encounter the same issue of being met with a white screen. My browser displays the current error: 
`The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique id property.
A row was provided without id in the rows prop:`

This is possibly due to the document being returned having other fields I am not establishing a uniqueID for since I only want to display the serial number, pc number, and the date attached to that document. Thanks so much for the help by the way.

Comment: This is already good. It means you need to create an id, which you don’t have in your api. Add this to your code. 
‘   const rows= useMemo(
    () =>
      cartsRounded.map((row, index) => ({
        ...row,
        id: row. serialNum
      })), 
    [cartsRounded],
  )’

Comment: And in jsx ‘rows={rows}

Comment: On my DB's side there is an id for that specific document. My document is returned from the API as such:
`_id: new ObjectId("61b9479422763a1760d2f4af"),
    cartSerialNumber: 'safgafasfafasaf',
    pcNumber: 'grdgrdgrdzgdgdg',
    isPowerCordDamaged: false,
    isFuseBlown: false,
    isInverterBad: false,
    isInterfaceDamaged: false,
    isPhysicalDamage: false,
    otherNotes: '',
    roundedBy: '6186c13beb18d33d5088f7b2',
    createdAt: 2021-12-15T01:40:36.355Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-12-15T01:40:36.355Z,
    __v: 0`

Comment: When adding that code I get the following error: 
`TypeError: t is not a function`

Comment: Is it called ‘id’?

Comment: It’s _id, but datagrid requires just ‘id’

Comment: Can you post please your updated code

Comment: Yeah, it is _id which is assigned by mongoDB server side. I tried playing with it with assigning the _id to the row id, but it still gives me that TypeError. And absolutely, one moment.

Comment: Code has been updated.

Comment: You didn’t update your jsx rows={rows}

Comment: And if doesn’t work try to update instead of _id, id:index

Comment: I'm so sorry! I had updated the wrong param. I no longer get the error, however it doesn't appear to be loading the data, but is showing how many documents (or rows in this case) there are:

https://i.imgur.com/xIRdgwU.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240157/discussion-between-jackgold-and-gregfan).